# How much professional development should I share on my CV?

Tags: career-path, cv

I am currently in the process of applying to Ph.D. programs in sociology and, as such, have started compiling my CV to accompany applications. As an M.A. student, I only have one publication to date and a couple of conference presentations. However, I have also taken part in several professional development activities over the course of my graduate study. Examples include...

- a workshop for which I received a certificate of completion
- a Lynda course relevant to my work
- attending non-conference presentations on topics relevant to my work

Which, if any, of these sorts of activities could (or should) viably be listed under professional development on my CV?

Comment: _•a workshop for which I received a certificate of completion_ Is that workshop relevant to your work?

Comment: @scaaahu Yes. It pertains to diversity in the classroom.

Answer (score 1):

It is very much better to include those courses/workshops you've attended, which you think has helped you to improve on that particular topic. After all, a good CV is the one that stands out from others. Also, when you add, it would be better if you could mention what you've learned from it(instead of just writing  "Attended the workshop on.... Etc etc.."). All the best!